# PL/SQL fetch records from JOIN clause problem

Tags: sql, plsql

It's the second question I'm asking for the same issue, so I'll try to be more specific and brief as I can.

In my pl/sql script, i try to insert into a table some records from lots of different tables. I achieve that, except for a field that comes from a `JOIN` of 2 tables.

The `INSERT` statement is placed into the following loop:

```
  FOR FST_DEMAND_rec IN (
  SELECT * 
   FROM A 
   WHERE  FK_DEPOSIT_ACCOACC = DEPOSIT_ACC_rec.ACCOUNT_NUMBER 
   AND TRX_DATE BETWEEN '01-JAN-2018' AND '31-DEC-2018'       
   ORDER BY TRANS_SER_NUM , ENTRY_SER_NUM ASC)
LOOP
```

This loop is placed into the following cursor loop :

```
 FOR T IN MOF_CURSOR LOOP
```

So the INSERT statement, which actually lies in 2 loops, is the following :

```
 INSERT INTO MOF_OUT
 VALUES(
    T.MOF_REQUEST_ID,                                               
    LOC_SERIAL_NUM,                                                   
   '2B',                                                                  
   CAST(FST_DEMAND_rec.TRX_UNIT || TO_CHAR(FST_DEMAND_rec.TRX_DATE,'YYYYMMDD') || FST_DEMAND_rec.TRX_USR || FST_DEMAND_rec.TRX_SN AS CHAR(50) ),          
   TO_CHAR(FST_DEMAND_rec.TRX_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') ,                    
   CAST(FST_DEMAND_rec.TRX_UNIT AS CHAR(4) ) ,                        
   UNIT_rec.UNIT_NAME ,                                               
   CAST(FST_DEMAND_rec.ID_TRANSACT AS CHAR(6) ),                      
   PRFT_TRANS_rec.DESCRIPTION,                                        
  -- 'MY PROBLEMATIC FIELD'                                                          
   TO_CHAR(FST_DEMAND_rec.TIMESTAMP,'hh24miss'),                      
   FST_DEMAND_rec.ENTRY_AMOUNT,                                       
   LOC_DC_FLAG,                                                         
   LOC_PROGR_BALANCE,                                                 
   LOC_PROGR_BAL_IND                                                              
  ) ;
```

This `INSERT` statement works fine, but I don't know how to fill a record which comes from the following `SELECT` statement with the `JOIN` clause:

```
  SELECT A.ENTRY_COMMENTS || '  ' || B.DESCRIPTION 
  FROM FST_DEMAND_EXTRAIT A INNER JOIN JUSTIFIC B ON A.ID_JUSTIFIC = B.ID_JUSTIFIC
```

For example, the `PRFT_TRANS_rec` variable that I use in the `INSERT`, it's declared as `PRFT_TRANSACTION%ROWTYPE;`  and I have the following `SELECT` statement for it which is within these 2 loops :

```
SELECT *
INTO PRFT_TRANS_rec 
FROM PRFT_TRANSACTION PRFT_TRANS
WHERE PRFT_TRANS.ID_TRANSACT = FST_DEMAND_rec.ID_TRANSACT;
```

Comment: I don't really understand how the insert statement and the query at the end are related. In general it is rarely necessary to write PL/SQL only to insert records into a table. You can simple write `insert into t (col1, col2, ...) select ...` and write a very complex query involving many tables. If you want to select one value from somewhere, you can always use a subquery, e.g. (`insert into t (col1, col2) values ('abc', (select col2_value from somewhere));`.

Comment: I don't want only to insert records into a table. This is just a part of a 1000 line PL/SQL script, and I don't know how to do it. Do i need to open a cursor? What do I declare?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand what you are trying to do. In PL/SQL you can select values of a single result row into variables, like in `select col1, col2 into v_col1, v_col2 from mytable where id = 123`. If you want to select multiple rows instead, you can either select into an array: `select col1, col2 bulk collect into v_array from mytable where id < 123` or use a loop like `for rec in (select col1, col2 from mytable where id < 123) loop ...`. Hope this helps.

Comment: How is the select statement concatenating the two columns related to the initial cursor? Also, if you've got nested loops happening, that sounds like it's begging to be combined into (at the very least) a single cursor + loop. More details would be helpful, including a script that we can copy and run ourselves (e.g. create table statements, sample data insert statements, etc).

Comment: You are right, i corrected the select statement.
I edited the initial post so you have an idea of how i get the values to insert them into my table. 
I don't know how to use the SELECT with the JOIN clause to collect the information I want.

Comment: It would help us to know what other sorts of things you're doing in your loops - for example, are you only doing things like string manipulations etc that could be done inside a SQL statement? Also, for your "problem" record - how do you know which record you need from the select statement for the jurisfic information? What is the link between your existing records and that select statement? Or does that select statement only ever return 1 row?

Comment: It returns only 1 row in my script, it represents one transaction. The FST_DEMAND_EXTRAIT table (which I loop) has half of the information I want. The other half is located into the JUSTIFIC table, so I want a row with the join of these two tables. I don't use the JUSTIFIC table elsewhere.

Comment: So your `SELECT A.ENTRY_COMMENTS || '  ' || B.DESCRIPTION FROM FST_DEMAND_EXTRAIT A INNER JOIN JUSTIFIC B ON A.ID_JUSTIFIC = B.ID_JUSTIFIC` query only ever returns a single row? If not, how do you specify which row you want to use in your insert statement, based on the cursor(s) in your PL/SQL? Is there a field in fst_demand_extrait or justific which is used to pick the right row?

Comment: What I'm asking is if there is a link between that select statement and the cursors in the PL/SQL, or whether it's completely independent.

Comment: I solved it, I got confused with no reason. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: The reason why I was asking is because it is more than likely possible to replace your code with a single insert statement - which will be faster and easier to maintain than your current code. If you could update your question to include what you ended up doing, it's possible we could help you re-write your code.